# Video call using Quickblox not connecting properly

Tags: xcode, quickblox

I am using using Quickblox API for video calling, user call to opponent user, then video call not connecting showing loader only

Comment: It's not quite clear what is the issue. Elaborate your request. What were your exact steps? What your logs show?